# Are there infinitely many positive integer solutions to $(3+3k+l)^2=m\,(k\,l-k^3-1)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I usually work in the field of differential geometry, but I have encountered the following problem in my research: Are there infinitely many positive integers $k,l,m\in\mathbb N^{>0}$ such that  $$(3+3k+l)^2=m\,(k\,l-k^3-1)\,?$$ Obviously, taking $l=k^2$
and $m=-(3+3k+l)^2$
gives infinitely many integer solutions, but  $m<0$ is negative. As a non-expert, I imagine that there is either a simple answer to this question, or the problem is not so simple to solve. Of course, I've played around with the equations a bit, but other than finding numerous examples, I haven't made any progress.

I would appreciate an existence or non-existence statement for infinitely many positive integer solutions, but also some hints that the problem is most likely hard to solve would help me.

Background: I am looking for certain integer representations of a surface group, and I can show that integer solutions to this diophantine equation actually give rise  to integer representations. The condition that $k,l,m$ are positive is equivalent to the condition that the corresponding representation is contained in a higher Teichmüller component (which is important for my differential geometric application).

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Writing $k = l^2+d$ reduces the problem to $(k^2+3k+3+d)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{kd-1}$, and then multiplying each side by $k^2$ (which is relatively prime to $kd-1$, so no extra solutions due to this), noting $kd \equiv 1 \pmod{kd-1}$, and using $(k+1)^3 = k^3+3k^2+3k+1$, one sees that your problem is equivalent to finding infinitely many positive integers $k,d$ for which $$kd-1 \mid (k+1)^6.$$

Comment: @mathworker21: From this perspective, the series from my answer gives divisibility $(kd-1)\mid (k+1)^4$. I wonder if for some other series the degree of $k+1$ can be lowered even further.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev My code is not finding any $(k,d) \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k \ge 15$ for which $(kd-1) \mid (k+1)^3$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Here is a proof that there are finitely many pairs $(k, d) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k d - 1 | (k + 1)^3$: multiplying the right hand side by $d^3$ and replacing $k d$ with $1$, this is equivalent to $k d - 1 | (d + 1)^3$, therefore WLOG $k \leq d$.
Now, if $(k + 1)^3 = m (k d - 1)$, then since $m = -1 (\bmod k)$ we have $m \geq k - 1$ and in fact $m = k - 1$ can happen only finitely often, therefore we can assume $m \geq 2 k - 1$. Thus, $(k + 1)^3 = m (k d - 1) \geq (2 k - 1) (k^2 - 1)$, which can happen for only finitely many $k$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It does have infinitely many positive solutions. Here is just one such series.

Consider the following recurrence sequence:

$$u_0=1,\ u_1=2,\ u_{n+1} = 23 u_n - u_{n-1} - 4\qquad (n\geq 1).$$

Let $t,k$ be any two consecutive terms of this sequence, then setting $l:=k^2+t$ produces the following equality:
$$(3+3k+l)(t+1) = (k+26)(kl-k^3-1),$$
which gives solution $m:=\frac{(k+26)(3+3k+l)}{t+1}$ (which is an integer) to the original equation.

---

In fact, integrality of $m$ follows from the identity:
$$(u_{n+2}+1)(u_n+1) = (u_{n+1}+26)(u_{n+1}+1),$$
which can be verified from the recurrence for $u_n$.

In summary, the values $(k,l,m)$ in this solution series are given by
$$\begin{cases}
k = u_{n+1}, \\
l = u_{n+1}^2 + u_n, \\
m = (u_{n+2}+2)(u_{n+1}+2) + 24.
\end{cases}\qquad (n\in\mathbb{Z}_+)
$$

---

**ADDED.** I've added $u_n$ to the OEIS as [sequence A350917](https://oeis.org/A350917). Together with 9 other similar recurrences it gives all solutions $k$ to $(tk-1)\mid (k+1)^4$, which are now listed in [sequence A350916](https://oeis.org/A350916).

Comment: Hi Max, your solution is great, many thanks. May we use your proof in our article. Of course, we will give you full credit for it.

Comment: @Sebastian: Sure. Btw, I've classified all solutions to $(tk-1)\mid (k+1)^4$ (which are given by 10 recurrences including the one from my answer) and believe it can also be done for $(tk-1)\mid (k+1)^6$ (i.e. obtaining *all* solutions to your equation). Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: What is the proof for your classification of all the solutions to $(tk-1)\mid(k+1)^4$?

Comment: @JovanRadenkovic: $(tk-1)\mid (k+1)^4$ is equivalent to $(tk-1)\mid (k^2 + t^2 + 4k + 4t + 6)$, which can be solved with [Vieta jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping).

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, can this method be used for an exponent greater than $4$?

Comment: @JovanRadenkovic: I do not see a general method here. Although variations of the [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) theme may produce some partial series of solutions, like [OEIS A001570](https://oeis.org/A001570) for the 6th power.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way maybe simpler as it reveals a certain Pell-Fermat equation. I don't know the relation with the other answer but i did many restrictions to get the following infinite sequence of solutions:

For $n\ge 1$, $$\begin{cases}q_n=-7q_{n-1}+24d_{n-1}\\d_n=2q_{n-1}-7d_{n-1}\end{cases}$$
with $q_0=3$ and $d_0=1$, (solutions of $q^2-12d^2=-3).$
Set $j=2|d_n|$, $i=4|d_n|+|q_n|$,  $r=3(i+j)$, so that $m=r^2$, $k=ij-1$ and $x:=3+3k+l=\dfrac{mk+r|j^3-i^3|}{2}$. This implies the positive integer solutions $(m,k,l)$ are infinite.
The starting equation to solve in $ x $ over $\mathbb{N}$ was $x^2-mkx+m(k+1)^3$.

Its discriminant is a square $X^2=(r\cdot y)^2$ as
$\Delta=X^2=m^2k^2-4m(k+1)^3$, say $m=r^2$ is a perfect square, then $(rk-y)(rk+y)=4(k+1)^3$ and set $(k+1)^3=i^3j^3$, ($k=ij-1$).
$$\begin{cases}rk-y=2i^3\\rk+y=2j^3\end{cases}.$$
So $r=(i+j)(-1+\dfrac{i^2+j^2-1}{ij-1})$ and $y=j^3-i^3$.
Let $\dfrac{i^2+j^2-1}{ij-1}=s$ an integer say $s=4$.
Finally we solve in $i$, $i^2+j^2-1=4ij-4$, taking again its discriminant to be a perfect (even)  square $p=2q$, $j=2d$ we solve $p^2-12j^2=-12$ as $q^2-12d^2=-3$.

Comment: This solution series is unrelated to my answer since the power of $k+1$ in divisibility here is 6. Btw, both $j$ and $i$ are recurrence sequences satisfying $a_n = 14a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$ for $n\geq 3$. They are present in the OEIS as [A094347](https://oeis.org/A094347) and [A011943](https://oeis.org/A011943), respectively. Also, they may be viewed as every other pair of consecutive terms of [A001075](https://oeis.org/A001075). The other pairs from this sequence, like $(7, 26)$ with $k=181$, also give solutions.

Comment: In fact, for the terms of [A001075](https://oeis.org/A001075) we have $a_n^6 \equiv a_{n+1}^6 \equiv -1 \pmod{a_na_{n+1}-1}$, proving that $k:=a_na_{n+1}-1$ is a solution to $(kt-1)\mid(k+1)^6$. These values of $k$ are given in [A001570](https://oeis.org/A001570).